# php, after split extra value in array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, split

I put in file this content:

```
12x4x11
12x17x20
4x19x30
5x18x10
17x6x18
19x30x20
11x2x17
30x13x19
22x23x7
17x28x2
5x17x30
```

When i read file line by line and spliting line with pattern 'x', to array always adding the extra space in array, so sorting array is not properly. Here code:

```
$array = array();
$handle = fopen("2.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $line = split('x', $line);
        //sort($line);
        print_r($line);
        array_push($array, $line);
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "File is failed to open";
}
```

How is looking array:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhLzQ.png

And after sorting:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t4V4.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the last element of your array before putting it in your array using the [array_pop](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-pop.php) function :

**PHP**

```
$array = array();
$handle = fopen("2.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $line = split('x', $line);
        array_pop($line);
        //sort($line);
        print_r($line);
        array_push($array, $line);
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "File is failed to open";
}
```

or you can use PHP [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function to remove space at the end of your line :

**PHP**

```
$array = array();
$handle = fopen("2.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $line = split('x', trim($line));
        //sort($line);
        print_r($line);
        array_push($array, $line);
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "File is failed to open";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the new line is part of the line you read. So for example in this line

12x4x11

The value 11 is in really is 11/n

/n is new line char.

The solution to this is easy just trim the line when you read it before splitting. That should remove new line char

Like this

```
$line = split('x', trim($line));
```